# Format a pandas dataframe and putting it in an email

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like an email that looks like this:
[image]

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'b': {0: 4, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 0, 4: 1},
 'c': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'd': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'e': {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 0},
 'f': {0: 4, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'g': {0: 3, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 0}})
```

Yes, I know that the picture does not match the data I am putting in.
The output I want is for the column headings to be centered with a light gray background.  All cells need to have a black border without any padding.

The background color of the table rows can be plain white (don't really need anything red).

From what little I understand in my ChatGPT questions, I have to convert the dataframe into HTML and then attach it to the body of the email.

Something like this:

```
email_server = 'appmail'
email_port = 25
email_sender = 'JenkinsDEV@acompany.com'
email_subject = 'Hung Subscriptions'
email_recipient = 'dlBusinessIntelligence@acompany.com'

# convert the DataFrame to an HTML table
html_table = df.to_html()

# Create the email message
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_sender
msg['To'] = email_recipient
msg['Subject'] = email_subject

# Attach the query result to the email body
msg.attach(MIMEText(html_table, 'html'))

# Connect to the email server and send the email
server = smtplib.SMTP(email_server, email_port)
server.starttls()
server.sendmail(email_sender, email_recipient, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

The above code results in this email being received:

[image]

Comment: to add css look into .set_table_styles() https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html

Comment: I appreciate the help.  The only problem is that when I do .set_table_styles(), it is lost when I do dataframe.to_html().  Am I missing something?

Comment: you would have to show that code for me to see what you are missing

Comment: [code block]
#create a CSS (cascading style sheet) to format the html table
html = '''
<style>
    .my_class {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .my_class td, .my_class th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    .my_class tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
    .my_class th {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
'''
html_table = df.to_html(classes='my_class')

Comment: Sry, tried to do a code block.  I really struggle with this stuff.

Comment: using raw css you would use .set_table_attributes('my_class') can you add to your question where you set the style object.

Comment: This still gives me the same results
html = '''
<style>
    .my_class {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .my_class th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 1px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: red;
    }
    .my_class td {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 1px;
    }
</style>
'''
df.style.set_table_attributes('my_class')

html_table = df.to_html()